# Adding images to website from network server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I have created a website and I need to load images from a folder on a network server. This works fine in IE, but not in Chrome, Edge or Firefox.

At the moment I have an `appSettings` in my web config file that points to the server and the required folder. I reference this in the code behind and append the relevant file name which is found from a stored procedure call.

I have spent the last couple of days looking into how best to solve the issue. So far I have created a virtual drive on `IIS` and I can browse to and see all the files listed in the folder on the server, I have also created a handler (`.ashx`).

What I am struggling with is connecting to the virtual directory via the handler. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: try checking how to put network path